# Class file not working online, C#

Tags: c#, class

I've created a class file to generate a calendar event for a website I'm working on that is written in C#.  Locally, I can add the class `using myNamespace` and I get no visible errors telling me that the type or namespace cannot be found.  Hovering over the class name in my code, it shows the correct definition.

However, when I upload the files to the web server, I get the error: `The type or namespace name 'vCalendar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

In visual studio, I can hover over `vCalendar` on the below:

`vCalendar myAppointment = new vCalendar("TCHR", "www.website.com");`

Hovering over the first gives me a message of `class myNamespace.vCalendar`, and hovering over the second gives me `vCalendar.vCalendar(string identifier, string netAddress)`.

My vCalendar class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public class vCalendar
    {
        private string identifier;
        private string netaddress;

        // Constructor:
        public vCalendar(string identifier, string netaddress)
        {
            this.identifier = identifier;
            this.netaddress = netaddress;
        }

        public string CreateAppointment(string uid, string organizer, DateTime startMeeting, DateTime endMeeting, string location, string summary, string description, int priority, int sequence)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            sb.AppendLine("PRODID:-// " + identifier + "//" + netaddress + "//EN");
            sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            sb.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            sb.AppendLine("UID:" + uid);
            sb.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:" + sequence.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("ORGANIZER:" + organizer);
            sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(startMeeting));
            sb.AppendLine("DTEND:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(endMeeting));
            sb.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(DateTime.Now));
            sb.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + location);
            sb.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + summary);
            sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + description);
            sb.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
            sb.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            sb.AppendLine("PRIORITY:" + priority.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("CLASS:PUBLIC");
            sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public string UpdateAppointment(string uid, string organizer, DateTime startMeeting, DateTime endMeeting, string location, string summary, string description, int priority, int sequence)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            sb.AppendLine("PRODID:-// " + identifier + "//" + netaddress + "//EN");
            sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            sb.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            sb.AppendLine("UID:" + uid);
            sb.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:" + sequence.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("ORGANIZER:" + organizer);
            sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(startMeeting));
            sb.AppendLine("DTEND:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(endMeeting));
            sb.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(DateTime.Now));
            sb.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + location);
            sb.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + summary);
            sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + description);
            sb.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
            sb.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            sb.AppendLine("PRIORITY:" + priority.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("CLASS:PUBLIC");
            sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public string CancelAppointment(string uid, string organizer, DateTime startMeeting, DateTime endMeeting, string location, string summary, string description, int priority, int sequence)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            sb.AppendLine("PRODID:-// " + identifier + "//" + netaddress + "//EN");
            sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            sb.AppendLine("METHOD:CANCEL");
            sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            sb.AppendLine("UID:" + uid);
            sb.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:" + sequence.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("ORGANIZER:" + organizer);
            sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(startMeeting));
            sb.AppendLine("DTEND:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(endMeeting));
            sb.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + ConvertToISO8601DateTime(DateTime.Now));
            sb.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + location);
            sb.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + summary);
            sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + description);
            sb.AppendLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
            sb.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            sb.AppendLine("PRIORITY:" + priority.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("CLASS:PUBLIC");
            sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static string ConvertToISO8601DateTime(DateTime dt)
        {
            string _dt = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", dt); // ISO 8601
            return _dt;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have uploaded all files to the web.  Am I doing something wrong in the class file?  Do I need to include this another way than the `using` command?

Comment: You have not copied the DLL that contains the `vCalendar` definition to the web server. In other words: your machine knows where it is, the web server does not.

Comment: Have you copied your class dll to the web server?'

Comment: @crashmstr It's not a DLL.  It's just a .cs file.  Does it have to be compiled as a DLL before I can use it like this?  But yes, the .cs file is online.

Comment: @James wow, I was not paying enough attention. Yes, you need to copy your compiled DLL to the web server, otherwise it cannot access the class in whatever web page/site that is using it.

Comment: @crashmstr Is there a way to include the class another way so that I do not have to compile it by chance?  Or is that really the only option I have to use it as a class?  (Sorry, fairly new to .Net still)

Comment: @James You need to compile it.

Comment: @crashmstr Well I've done that and it's working.  Can you write that up in an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use your C# `class` from a web site, you need to compile the project to a DLL, and then copy the DLL to the web server so that your web code can use it.